# How to disable indexing of a specific storage in Outlook 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, outlook-2013

For earlier versions of Outlook I use solution described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716229/1741116 , and it works fine for me.

But in Outlook 2013 intercommunication with Windows Search has been removed (http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2012/12/19/outlook-2013-deprecated-features-and-components.aspx), and even Outlook item in Indexing Options is not expandable anymore.

[image: non-expandable outlook item]

Modifying the value in registry key ('20' at the end is actually only for my machine)

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\CrawlScopeManager\Windows\SystemIndex\WorkingSetRules\20
```

from

```
mapi15://{S-1-5-21-1397509461-1896107085-1961542790-1001}/
```

to

```
mapi://{S-1-5-21-1397509461-1896107085-1961542790-1001}/
```

adds expandable Outlook item

[image: expandable outlook item]

and I can exclude locations from indexing by WDS (programmatically or by hand), but still not able to prevent my specific storage from indexing by Outlook 2013. Can anyone suggest me an answer or a link to resource with explanation of my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to use the Crawl Scope Manager and register a URL for your store. The full details are documented here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2013/12/31/wrapped-pst-and-indexing.aspx

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I read the link but I am lost. What is a wrapped PST? What is a store? When the article says: "You can do this by calling AddUserScopeRule", calling where? Do I need to program this?  Thanks (and sorry for ignorance)