# Use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook from c# to access non-default profiles

Tags: c#, windows, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

I'm trying to pull Outlook store information from the non-default profile. The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716229/12282925) does essentially what I want, except it only pulls from the default profile. According to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.logon), I should be able to specify the profile with the NameSpace.Logon method. But no matter what I specify with NameSpace.Logon, I only get stores from the default profile.

For example, this code just outputs the default profile ("Outlook"), not the "archive" profile:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
...
Application objApp = null;
NameSpace ns = null;
objApp = new Application();
ns = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.Logon("archive");
Console.WriteLine(ns.Session.CurrentProfileName);
```

I've also tried using the Logon method with the Application.Session object, rather than the Application.Namespace object, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that no `outlook.exe` processes exist in the list of running processes. Outlook is a singleton, if any instance has not been closed and still running on the system, you will not be able to logon to another profile and continue dealing with the current session/profile.

Comment: Are you sure outlook.exe is a singleton? I can open multiple instances of outlook at the same time. In fact I just had to add a flag to the shortcut to prevent that default behavior.

Comment: Yes, unlike other Office applications. Which flag did you add? And do you still get the default profile when no Outlook processes are run on the system?

Comment: I am getting the same result starting with Outlook closed (verified in task manager and pslist). I'd also welcome other ideas of how to programatically get information about the non-default profiles.

Comment: There is no other way. You need to use the [Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.logon?view=outlook-pia) method, however, you may try to specify all parameters. I'd suggest trying the `ShowDialog` option enabled, so you could be sure the correct profile can be chosen programmatically.

Comment: I've tried setting `ShowDialog` to `true` and no box appears, so it seems like the function is silently failing. Is it possible it's just broken with O365? Any ideas for narrowing the issue?

Comment: Seems like it may be possible to do this with MrMAPI. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The dialog is not displayed in one case only - if you have the session alive already. That means it was not closed from the previous time or used by somebody else.

Comment: Outlook is launched with the “new Application()” line, so by the time it gets to Logon() function there is already a process running. Is there a different way it should be done?

Comment: It shouldn't make any sense. However, you may try connecting to the running instance first. But it may work only if both applications are run under the same security context.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out why this wasn't working with c# code, but I did find the command-line tool [MrMAPI](https://microsoft.github.io/mfcmapi/), which can get me most of the way there. `mrmapi -profile` lists the profiles available, and then `mrmapi -profile (profile_name) -store (store_name)` dumps metadata associated with each of the stores for the specified profile. From there I can extract the other information I need. I would like to figure out why the Interop code shown above never worked but this is a reasonable workaround.

Incidentally, mrmapi is able to retrieve info about other profiles even when Outlook is running with the default profile. I don't know if this contradicts the singleton observation above or if mrmapi is accessing the profiles some other way.